# C# - extract HTML from JSON

Tags: c#, html, json

**Original:**  
*I want to remove the characters from a string before the first `IndexOf("<")` and after the `LastIndexOf(">")`. 

There probably is a more efficient way to do this then what I did. My question now is, could anyone tell me this efficient way (if there is one)?*  

***My Code:***

```
string body_string = body.ToString();
string new_body = body_string.Substring(0, body_string.LastIndexOf(">") + 1);
string htmlbody = new_body.Substring(new_body.IndexOf("<"));
```

*Thank you!*

**Update:**  
I realized my original question was not what I was really looking for so Im trying again.  
I used a GET method via REST API on a Confluence page. What I got is a JSON with HTML code from the page content as a value. Now I want to kind of "filter" the JSON to only get the HTML out of it.  
As you can see in my code above my original idea was to convert the JSON to a string and then kind of filter through it but there is probably a way more efficient way to do this. 
How can I achieve this?

**Code:**

```
    public static class Http
    {
        private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        [FunctionName("Http")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> getContentByID(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
              ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            //Set up Configuration Builder
            var confBuild = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            //Basic Authentication
            var user = confBuild["ConfluenceUser"];
            var api = confBuild["ConfluenceAPI"];
            var domain = confBuild["ConfluenceDomain"];
              httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", user, api))));

            object body;
            string new_body, htmlbody;

            //Get content from page
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(
                        $"https://{domain}/wiki/rest/api/content/{id}?expand=body.storage"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               
                body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
                string body_string = body.ToString();

                //Extract HTML from JSON
                new_body = body_string.Substring(0, body_string.LastIndexOf(">") + 1);
                htmlbody = new_body.Substring(new_body.IndexOf("<"));
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(htmlbody);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are - what does the text look like? Where does it come from?  Is it XML or HTML?  You may be able to use a Regex or, if it's XML, an XML library and retrieve the inner text of the tag or element you want. If `body` is an XmlDocument or XDocument you can retrieve the node you want and get its inner text without converting to string

Comment: if this is XML, you should **not** manipulate that on your own. Instead you should de-serialize it to an object and manipulate that instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The original body is JSON with HTML code inside of it as a value. I want to extract the HTML code out of the JSON

Comment: @Nina then parse json and use parsed object to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, takes linear time, no regex fsa and backtracking:

```
    public static string Crop(string input)
    {
        if(input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        var i = 0;
        var j = input.Length-1;
        for(i = 0; i < input.Length-1;i++)
           if(input[i] == '<')
              break;
        for(j = input.Length-1; j > i; j--)
           if(input[j] == '>')
              break;
        var start = i+1;
        var length = j-i-1;
        if(start >= 0 && start < input.Length && length > 0)
             return input.Substring(start, length);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `RegEx`

```
string body_string = "my test <result> is inside";

var reg = new Regex(string.Format("(?<={0})(.+?)(?={1})", Regex.Escape("<"), Regex.Escape(">")));
var result = reg.Match(body_string).ToString();
```

Comment: Will fail: "my test <result <result2>>"

Comment: good point @eocron, but unfortunately there is no clarity on how the input string look like

Comment: I agree, but OP clarify what he needs first and last characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the substring between (firs index of "<") and (last index of ">"):

```
string input = "<Some String>";
        int startIndex = input.IndexOf("<"); //return firs appear index of "<"
        int endIndex = input.LastIndexOf(">");
        int count = (endIndex - startIndex) -1;
        string result = input.Substring(startIndex + 1,count); //Substring starts at (startIndex) and have (count) legth!
```

result = Some String